# How to write a Roblox script to save a players backpack and starter gear when they die?

Tags: lua, save, roblox

I have written a few different scripts and I can't seem to get it right.
Basically I have a store where players can buy tools and items from, but every time I test it and buy a tool, after I die the tool is gone. I don't want people to have to buy over and over again.

Here is the script for them buying the tool and where the tool will go.

```
script.Parent.MouseButton1Click:connect(function()
local RS = game:GetService('ReplicatedStorage')
local item = RS:WaitForChild('GravityCoil')
local price = 0
local player = game.Players.LocalPlayer
local stats = player:WaitForChild('leaderstats')

if stats.Cash.Value >= price then
    stats.Cash.Value = stats.Cash.Value - price
    local cloned = item:Clone()
    local cloned2 = item:Clone()
    cloned2.Parent = player.Backpack
end
end)
```

Comment: Does this code contain an attempt at saving/loading this data? If not, have you looked at the docs to see if these operations are supported, and how you might begin to tackle this problem?

Answer (score 2):

Don't use replicated storage. What happens is you can't add to it, and it gets stored to each client when they re spawn. I used to use the "Lighting" before the new storage systems were brought about. Anyway, if you're not looking to save it across each time a player joins the game, create a model in a storage system of your choice. Name it the character's name, and have the backpack save to this model each time an item is added or removed via your purchase system. Then, when the player spawns, copy the stuff in the model to the backpack. I would use ServerStorage instead. 
Then for each object in the player's model, copy it to the player's backpack when they respawn.

```
script.Parent.MouseButton1Click:connect(function()
local RS = game:GetService('ServerStorage')
local item = RS:WaitForChild('GravityCoil')
local price = 0
local player = game.Players.LocalPlayer
local stats = player:WaitForChild('leaderstats')

if stats.Cash.Value >= price then
    stats.Cash.Value = stats.Cash.Value - price
    local cloned = item:Clone()
    local cloned2 = item:Clone()
    local plrMod = Instance.new("Model")
    plrMod.name = player.name
    plrMod.parent = RS
    cloned.parent = plrMod
    cloned2.Parent = player.Backpack
end
end)
```

Then a portion of code for the onRespawn event would look like

```
for child in plrMod
    child:Clone().parent = player
```

Note, this is not proper syntax, it has been several years sinc eI have done lua programming

Comment: Also remember that if the answer works for you, to accept it as the answer to help not only the answerer, but yourself and others so they know what can work when they have the same issue.

Comment: What do you mean by "name it the character's name"? Sorry for the really late response, but any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: @HappyGamerBro All the players have name. You name the model after the player you are storing. That's what is going on in the line "plrMod.name = player.name"